# Documentation of google docs viewer

Tags: javascript, html, google-docs

Its look weird but i am not getting where is the documentation of google docs viewer to embed in my website. https://docs.google.com/viewer here is link where I can only generate links. Actually i want to increase or remove the timeout check because i cant view files with big sizes. Here is what i am doing right now

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="www.urltopdf.pdf&embedded=true"width="1000" height="800" ></iframe>
```

and with big files getting following error.

```
Sorry, it took too long to find the document at the original source. Please try again later.
You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Here is a page with a form that generate a link to the document viewer : https://docs.google.com/gview</s>

[EDIT]  Google may have deprecated this functionnality.

In this page, there is a very minimal documentation that you may already have seen, but I didn't find any other documentation about it, and the search "gview" gave 0 result in developers.google.com.

There are also other similar issues about Joomla or Wordpress plugins using this viewer.

**As an alternative** to this viewer, if you host these files in Google Drive, you can use the google drive's built-in preview functionnality :

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/fileID/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

You can easily access to this from any previewed document from Google Drive by clicking on `⋮` then  `integrate element`.

Comment: Google may have removed this functionallity.  I will edit the comment.  Otherwise, this may be a working example: `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9PHCu09NNa0VWl2cTlHbUV0M1k/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>`.  Paste this in your URL bar to see if it works for you: `data:text/html,<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9PHCu09NNa0VWl2cTlHbUV0M1k/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>`.

Comment: Sept 2023 - this works.